# Rust, OpenSSL, solana-test-validator library not loaded issue

Tags: macos, rust, openssl, homebrew, solana

I am on Mac(M1) Big Sur 11.4, Homebrew version 3.2, OpenSSL@1.1

I try to run solanar-test-validator in their [README](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/blob/master/README.md)
, I install open ssl with homebrew then I linked the openssl

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/
```

When I run solana validate, it occur error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use rosetta, as outlined in the readme at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana#1-install-rustc-cargo-and-rustfmt

There isn't a native M1 build yet.

Comment: Thanks, I have ask in many group but no answer. I will try your answer.

Comment: After follow the instruction in solana it occur new error : 


`
Ledger location: test-ledger Log: test-ledger/validator.log ⠙ Initializing... zsh: illegal hardware instruction solana-test-validator
`. 
I find a lot of people have same issue. It look like the dependency which solana use is still not run smoothy on M1. I think solana dev team should work more to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

without Rosetta:

#### fetch

```sh
git clone https://github.com/solana-labs/solana.git
```

#### build

```sh
cd solana/validator
```

in `solana/validator`

```sh
echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash

here="$(dirname "$0")"
set -x
exec cargo build --release --manifest-path="$here"/Cargo.toml --bin solana-test-validator -- "$@"' > solana-test-validator
./solana-test-validator
```

#### test

```sh
cd ../target/release
```

in `solana/target/release`

```sh
./solana-test-validator
```

#### link

Since I was using this with the original installed solana tools, I added the path to my shell config (~/.zshrc or ~/.bash_profile on mac). Just make sure that you are able to find the binary or the symlink to it after typing `$which solana-test-validator`
What I added to my .zshrc:

```sh
export PATH="/Users/lain/git/solana/solana-src/target/release:$PATH"
```

of course, **replace the user**.

[Source and full credit](https://dev.to/codenjobs/how-to-make-solana-test-validator-work-with-a-macbook-with-m1-chip-5emd)